# Get the returned value of Java Script to server side

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf

I'm in my up-skilling process of JSF
and I'm trying to get the current location from JS to JSf and then pass it back to FirstBean.nowLoc bean. I've tried so many options but no luck :(
Could anyone please help me?

```
<h:message id="errors" for="User_ID" style="color:red" />
        <h:form id="getLoc">
            <h3>
                 <h:inputHidden id="xxx" binding="#{FirstBean.nowLoc}" /> 

            </h3>
        </h:form>
        <p>
            <h:outputText id="c"
                value="currentLocation ----- #{FirstBean.currentLocation }"/>

            <h:outputText id="x" value="nowLoc-------------->#{FirstBean.nowLoc}"/>



            <script>
            getLocation();
            function getLocation() {

                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

                } else {
                    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
                }



            }

            function showPosition(position) {
                loc = "***Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude
                        + "***Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
                document.getElementById("getLoc:xxx").value = loc;

                return loc;

            }
        </script>
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you're asking.  Are you asking how to send the current location from your web page back to your server?

Comment: That's exactly right! Right now i get nowLoc-------------->javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputHidden@623823bc but I want to see "***Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude
                        + "***Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; when I call FirstBean.nowLoc

Comment: You need to use an ajax call to send data to your server.  Create an endpoint on your server and then send data to that endpoint with an ajax call.

Comment: do you ever call `getLocation()` ? Why the special characters in element ID?

Comment: Inside the scripts I call the getLocarion()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few ways of passing from JS to backing Bean, all ugly I'm afraid, but all described well in this [post](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)

To sum-up the way I use the most (though I really try to design so that I'm never in a need of this), is what in the post is described is as follows

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:inputText id="inputId" value="#{bean.property}" />
    <h:commandButton id="buttonId" value="Button" action="#{bean.action}" />
</h:form>
```

so a JSF form (often invisible), and a js piece of code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('formId:inputId').value = 'foo';
    document.getElementById('formId:buttonId').click();
    // Or: document.getElementById('formId').submit();
</script>
```

So if you can't avoid this, pass in values, and target your beans, and you'll have your solution

Comment: I couldn't work JS click and submit yet. Is there anyway that I can fulfil the action without a button or link?